# Create a panorama slider in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently working on a gallery website with react and I would like to create a slider that has a panoramic effect such as the one shown below:
[image]

I am currently using Swiper.js with the code below:

```
<Swiper
        modules={[Navigation, A11y, EffectCoverflow]}
        spaceBetween={50}
        slidesPerView={5}
        initialSlide={1}
        effect="coverflow"
        coverflowEffect={{
          rotate: 15,
          // stretch: 0,
          depth: 100,
          modifier: 1,
          slideShadows: false,
        }}
        onSlideChange={() => console.log("slide change")}
        onSwiper={(s) => setSwiper(s)}
        onSliderMove={(s, e) => {
          moveSecondCursor(e.clientX, e.clientY);
        }}
      >
        {slides.map((slide) => (
          <SwiperSlide
            className=" odd:bg-blue-400 even:bg-blue-700"
            onMouseEnter={() => toggleCursor(true)}
            onMouseLeave={() => toggleCursor(false)}
            onClick={(e) => openCard(e, slide.id)}
            key={slide.id}
          >
            <div className="slide-content cursor-none slide-item w-full flex items-center justify-center">
              {slide.text}
            </div>
          </SwiperSlide>
        ))}
      </Swiper>
```

Using the above code, i was able to obtain the following effect:
[image]

But it is not yet exactly what i need. Does anyone have an idea on how i can achieve the right effect?

Comment: It seems like swiper.js has a demo code for a panorama carousel, but it is paid for and you must have a patreon account to access it. anyone can help? https://uiinitiative.com/catalog/panorama-slider

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use the panorama effect just like this picture shown below [image]

**OPTION 1** :
there is  [Swiper studio](https://studio.swiperjs.com/) you need to connect your Patreon account in order to export the panorama effect.

**OPTION 2** :
because the effect is not yet available on  [SwiperJs in GitHub](https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/blob/master/src/components-shared/params-list.js) so you can fork the swiperJs repo and create your custom effect and put it in the module directory,

**Note** :
you can't Override the CSS of the effect because it's an inline style made with SwiperJs